# Markdown bug (HTML code right after numbered list)

Tags: bug

If I add a numbered list then empty line, then paste HTML and mark this HTML as "code" by adding indentation - the HTML becomes invisible. Like this:

```
 1.blah
 2.blah
 3.blah

<html><code></html>
```

Workaround: add some non-empty text between list and HTML code.

It was just reproduced at Stack Overflow.